# Xcode 9 Beta 2 fails - DVTPlugInErrorDomain plugin load fails

Tags: xcode9-beta

After downloading from Apple's site and installing Xcode 9 beta 2, it fails to launch on Sierra OS X version 10.12.5 with a following bug report:

> Process:               Xcode [4789] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               9.0 (13158.29) Build Info:
>   IDEFrameworks-13158029000000000~6 Code Type:             X86-64
>   (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           Xcode
>   [4789] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2017-07-10 09:27:38.822 +0300 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F73) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   D8406E47-CD80-D96B-2976-599E84980DE2
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       A8F0AF0B-2FF1-45A9-89AD-505F25730705
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 20000 seconds Time Since Wake:       3800
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 9M137d UNCAUGHT
>   EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for
>   parameter key 'name' of extension
>   'Xcode.InterfaceBuilderKit.PepperIntegration.Singletons' in plug-in
>   'com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration' UserInfo: {
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\"
>   UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration,
>   DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite
>   plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.,
>   DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration,
>   0): Library not loaded:
>   /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator\n
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SimulatorKit.framework/Versions/A/SimulatorKit\n
>   Reason: image not found, NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in
>   failed.,
>   NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in
>   \U201ccom.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration\U201d
>   at path
>   \U201c/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework\U201d
>   could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins
>   may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc8df3cb340 {Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587
>   \"dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator\n
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SimulatorKit.framework/Versions/A/SimulatorKit\n
>   Reason: image not found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The
>   bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle.,
>   NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration,
>   NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration):
>   Library not loaded:
>   /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator\n
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SimulatorKit.framework/Versions/A/SimulatorKit\n
>   Reason: image not found,
>   NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle
>   \U201cIDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration\U201d couldn\U2019t be
>   loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}}}"; }

Comment: I just updated to Xcode 9 from 8.1 and ouch, same error.

Answer (score 73):

I had the same issue. I have reinstalled `XcodeSystemResources.pkg` package. You will find it in here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSys‌​temResources.pkg
```

The installer will recreate `/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks` folder with its content. After that Xcode 9 started working for me.

Comment: You saved my day. After hours of trial and error finally I have a working Xcode9. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This saved me after a rm -rf mishap

Comment: Thanks! I had the same error but for a different extension. Reinstalling the package worked!

Comment: Thank you so very much! Wow ... I don't know what I'd have done without this answer.  BTW, I found the package at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg so it is no longer beta.

Comment: This also works for Xcode 11.4. I deleted the app and some of the related files, but missed a few. Upon re-installing Xcode, I continued to get a similar error message. Running `XcodeSystemResources.pkg` cleared my error and I was able to open Xcode, with no problems. Adding this as answer because I don't have 50 reputation points to comment on the above working answer.

Comment: Command to run `sudo installer -pkg /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg -target /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks`